# Get-WinEvent doesn't show older entries

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to read the SQL Agent Log.

```
Get-WinEvent -filterhashtable @{logname='application';starttime='21.07.2021 05:00:00';providerName='SQLAgent$MyInstance'}
```

the only results I get are from 22.07.2021, when I open the Log File Viewer on SQL Server I can see the entries from 21.07.2021, they are part of the current log file?
Another question is: how to read the entries from archived files?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [DBATools](https://docs.dbatools.io/) toolset, it has many useful functions that perform things just like what you need here.

Take a look at this [function](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaAgentLog) of theirs that coverts the SQL Agent Log.

```
Get-DbaAgentLog -SqlInstance "Server\Instance"
```

Comment: It's not the point using dbatools (which I'm using frequently), it's a different approach, it must be doable using get-winevent.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-winevent` reads the Windows event logs, when you use the SQL server log viewer it is reading the text file that the agent writes log output to.

Comment: using: get-winevent -computername "MyComp" -listprovider '*agent*' gives back: Name=SQLAgent$myComp, LogLinks=Application which actually means: the log entries would be written to Windows Log Application, or not?

Comment: SQL agent is probably writing to both, I was pointing out that the two ways you were viewing the logs were not looking at the same source. Is it possible your application event log had already rolled round so the older events were not there?